# How is Amazon Lightsail cheaper than EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

There is only one apparently abstract upside of using Lightsail, simplicity, or significantly simplified interface.

Also, the first page of Lightsail talks about **lower charges.** 
My question is how is it considered to reduce charges compared to EC2? Consider $5 Lightsail plan which charges **$0.0067/hour** of an instance (which is the cheapest) where EC2's same type of instance (t2.nano) costs just **$0.0059/hour**.

What am I missing? A detailed price comparison would be much appreciated showing how Lightsail costs lower as advertised.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [$5 Amazon LightSail plan](https://amazonlightsail.com/pricing/) includes:

- A CPU that appears similar to a `t2.nano` ($0.0059c/hr in US regions) = approximately $4.25/month
- 20GB SSD storage, similar to Amazon EBS general purpose SSD (10c/GB/month) = $2/month
- 1TB data transfer (9c/GB = approximately $92 in US regions)

So, the real saving appears to be in **Data Transfer**.

Comment: Also I think corresponding Lightsail instance memory is higher (1GB) vs EC2 nano 512 MB

Comment: Note that while this was true in 2017, as of 2019, Lightsail can easily be cheaper than ec2, for compute alone. For example, without reservation, a t3.nano is $0.0052/hr (~$3.87/mo), while Lightsail charges only $3.50/mo. (a t2.nano, which I think is what Lightsail uses behind-the-scenes, is currently $0.0058/hr (~$4.32/mo)).

That's for a nano, the smallest instance. Now compare: a t2.2xlarge, to the current largest instance available on Lightsail: Lightsail costs $160/mo, while a t2.2xlarge would be $193.25/mo even with 1-year full-upfront reservation. Lightsail wins very easily here.

Comment: @WillPalmer Thanks for the update

Answer (score -6):

Also with lightsail you get a static IP built into the price, with ec2 it’s about $4/month

Comment: That's not truth. IPs are free when some conditions are met. You can get one IP per EC2 instance for free. Also, the EC2 instance must be running. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/